# iTunes connect enable game center

Tags: app-store-connect, game-center

I try to test Game Center in my iPhone game, but when I try to connect with the following lines of code I get an alert that says "This game is not recognized by Game Center.".

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil)
    {
        // Insert code here to handle a successful authentication.
    }
    else
    {
        // Your application can process the error parameter to report the error to the player.
    }
}];
```

Now I've read many forums and looked at the Apple documentation, but I can't find how I can enable the Game Center option at iTunes connect. I think I need to first add an application to "Manage application" and then enable the Game Center option. But how can I add an application only for testing?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was in wrong cocos2d version. After moving to v0.99.5 game center started working.

Comment: Cocos2d has nothing to do with Game Center.

Answer (score 0):

I am testing an iPad app with the iPad simulator. I was having a similar problem.

I had followed all the steps as specified in the "Game Kit Programming Guide", including setting up iTunes Connect. Even so I was still getting the error message: This game is not recognized by game center"

My app was only recognized when I deleted it from the simulator and re-installed it, as suggested by iMuller.