# Is developer provisioning profile/code signing required to test game center in simulator?

Tags: game-center

I am in a strange problem of getting "this application is not recognized by Game Center".

I developed a game which is in the App Store with no Game Center option. Now I am working on it to make it Game Center-enabled. A few hours ago, I enabled Game Center and added leaderboard and achievements using iTunes Connect. Now when I try to access Game Center in the iPhone Simulator it gives me the following error:

> GameKitHelper ERROR: {
>       NSLocalizedDescription = "The requested operation could not be
>   completed because this application is not recognized by Game Center.";
>   }

The bundle ID of the application is the same as the application that is uploaded in iTunes Connect, but I don't have any valid provisioning profile now, so there is no code signing in my application.

Now my question is this: Does it require a provisioning profile associated with the corresponding application to test with Game Center in the simulator? Or is it sufficient that just the application bundle ID matches the uploaded application bundle ID? If the second case is true then why am I getting this error?

I am using a sandbox account which is generated from the simulator. So certainly it is sandbox account.

Please, someone help me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937972/itunes-connect-enable-game-center/4145174#4145174

Comment: No, that's not the same. I have specific question which is not related to that question though both have same problem.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from your simulator and installing it again ? Because that was the point of the link (and I've read this a few times that it did solve the problem). So I'd do: delete the app from simulator, Product->Clean, Product->Run.

Comment: I did it so many times, but nothing happens. The main question is that whether or not i need a provisioning profile for testing game center in simulator bcoz i don't have any provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

The bundle ID is case sensitive. Make sure they really are the same.